# Coded ui VS2017 ordered list alternatives

Tags: uwp, coded-ui-tests, ordered-test

I have a UWP application and codedui testcases project for this app which I put them in playlist in visual studio 2017 
but the playlist doesn't run testcases in order so I searched online and people suggested using orderedtest, but when I try to add an orderedtest I can't find such file type in VS
what should I add as a plugin or is it not supported in vs2017 ? 
Also is orderedtest my only option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try following these instructions? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx

As an alternative, you could do this manually. You can create a new test method that call's the other test methods in the order you would like them to execute. No need for a playlist that way.

Comment: I tried this link before but I can't find this file type to add to the project. It seems there is only one alternative that u suggested sofar .. Thank you

Comment: I just checked, I'm running visual studio enterprise 2017 version 15.7.6. When I right-click my Coded UI Test Project and go to "add" I have a "Ordered Test" entry. Clicking on it gives me a new ordered test.
I can think of 2 possible explanations to why you don't have that menu entry:
1. You don't run vs2017 pro or enterprise
2. The project you are trying to add that ordered test to, is not a CUIT project
3. You need to install additional components or reinstall corrupted components trough the vs setup. Look at "individual components".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have visual studio enterprise 15.7.5 and I installed or testing components too. 
I found ordered test but under project Codedui C# and visual basic type not 
 codedui for uwp application

Comment: np @memok. I'm not sure that I understand your answer completely.
As far as I know, you can only have ordered tests on a test project. It shoulden't matter what type of project you are running your tests for.